# Render global footer in react-native-router-flux 3.x

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have an app where on all scenes I want to render a global navigation footer at the bottom of the screen. This was a very easy thing to do in RNRF 2.x with the footer prop, but I'm having quite a lot of trouble implementing it in 3.x since the footer prop does not exist anymore. Anyone know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with only React Native. Just wrap your old main component in a new View that contains the old main component and the footer. Then the footer will always be shown.

Assuming you have a main component named `MainComponent` in a file `path/to/main/component.js`:

```
// path/to/main/component.js
export default class MainComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
}
```

Just change it to this:

```
// path/to/main/component.js
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
}

export default () => (
    <View styles={styles.newMainComponent}>
        <MainComponent />
        <GlobalFooter />
    </View>
);
```

You may need to move some styles from your old main component to the new view that wraps it.

Comment: Ok, I ran into this in the migration guide for RNRF so I wasn't sure if that was the recommended way: ```Router is root container now and should not be nested. For nested scenes you should use Scene element.``` But maybe that only refers to not nesting it in a scene. Managed to solve the problem by using the navBar prop of Router, which took me a while to figure out since the docs are what they are... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Good! Since you found a different and perhaps better solution for your problem, there would be nothing wrong with adding that as a new answer and accepting that one :)