# How to add existing component to the react-native-router-flux

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I want to add my current header and footbar to my react-native-router-flux router. But I don't know how to do that properly. This is my header

```
class Button extends Component {
  handlePress(e) {
    if (this.props.onPress) {
      this.props.onPress(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this)}
        style={this.props.style}
      >
        <Text>{this.props.children}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}


class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      selectedItem: 'About'
    };
  }

  onMenuItemSelected(item) {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: false,
      selectedItem: item
    });
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  updateMenuState(isOpen) {
    this.setState({ isOpen });
  }

  render() {
    const menu = <Menu onItemSelected={this.onMenuItemSelected} />;
    return (
      <SideMenu
        menu={menu}
        isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
        onChange={(isOpen) => this.updateMenuState(isOpen)}
        menuPosition='right'
      >
      <LoginForm />
      <Button style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.toggle()}>
          <Image
            source={{ uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/vKRaKDX.png', width: 32, height: 32 }}
          />
      </Button>
      </SideMenu>
    );
  }
}
```

This is footer

```
class FootBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props.page);
    if (this.props.page !== undefined) {
      this.state = {
        page: this.props.page
      };
    }
    this.state = {
      page: 'home'
    };
    this.pageChange = this.pageChange.bind(this);
  }

  pageChange(page) {
    this.setState({page});
    switch (page) {
      case 'home':
        Actions.login(page);
        break;
      case 'user-plus':
        Actions.registerUser(page);
        break;
      case 'car':
        Actions.CarList(page);
        break;
      case 'user':
        Actions.Profile(page);
        break;
      case 'truck':
        Actions.CreateCar(page);
        break;
      case 'camera-retro':
        Actions.OpenCamera(page);
        break;
      default:
        Actions.login(page);
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Tabs
          selected={this.state.page}
          style={{
            borderTopWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'lightgrey',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            paddingTop: 1,
          }}
          onSelect={el => this.pageChange(el.props.name)}
        >
          <Icon style={styles.icon} name='home' size={30} color='#rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.65)'/>
          <Icon style={styles.icon} name='user-plus' size={29} color='#rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.65)'/>
          <Icon style={styles.icon} name='car' size={29} color='#rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.65)'/>
          <Icon style={styles.icon} name='user' size={31} color='#rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.65)'/>
          <Icon style={styles.icon} name='truck' size={30} color='#rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.65)'/>
          <Icon style={styles.icon} name='camera-retro' size={29} color='#rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.65)'/>
        </Tabs>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the router where I want to add my header as the header that every component can have it, and add my footer as the footer that can navigate the user around my app

```
class RouterComponent extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <Router duration={0}>
          <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} initial />
          <Scene key="showCar" component={showCar} />
          <Scene key="registerUser" component={RegisterForm} />
          <Scene key="CarList" component={CarList} />
          <Scene key="CarDetail" component={CarDetail} />
          <Scene key="bookCar" component={bookCar} />
          <Scene key="Profile" component={Profile} />
          <Scene key="Confirmation" component={Confirmation} />
          <Scene key="CreateCar" component={CreateCar} />
          <Scene key="CarPhotos" component={CarPhotos} />
          <Scene key="AdditionalCarInfo" component={AdditionalCarInfo} />
          <Scene key="OpenCamera" component={OpenCamera} />
    </Router>
  );
}
}
```

Currently I can't find a way to do that? Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If having the same header and footer on each Scene is all you want, one approach is to export the header and footer components and then importing them into each Scene.

```
export class FootBar extends Component {...}
```

Then in each Scene at the top have:

```
import {Footbar} from '../your/path/to/Footbar.js';
```

Then in the Scene be sure to call the component in the render function

```
...
render() {
    return (
        ...
        <FootBar/>   
    )
}
```

Comment: what I want is actually add header and footer in the router, so the scene can be changed nicely

Comment: Ah I see, well take a look at this answer and see if it's more of what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/36262494/5287007

Answer (score 0):

If by header you mean a custom navbar then yes, there is a way to achieve [this](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/OTHER_INFO.md#custom-nav-bar-for-individual-scene-or-even-different-state-of-scene-new-feature) .
As for the footer, I think the only way is to do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393552/render-global-footer-in-react-native-router-flux-3-x)